# Different results between Google Embed API vs Query Explorer

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-chart-api

I'm new to working with the GA Embed API. When I execute the following query:

```
 var timeline = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
        reportType: 'ga',
        query: {
            'dimensions': 'ga:hour',
            'metrics': 'ga:goal1Completions',
            'start-date': '2017-11-21',
            'end-date': '2017-11-21',
            sort:'ga:hour'
        },
        chart: {
            type: 'TABLE',
            container: 'timeline',
            options:{
                width:'100%',
                colors: ['#e0440e', '#e6693e', '#ec8f6e', '#f3b49f', '#f6c7b6']
            }
        }
    });
```

I see the following results:

[image: Results examples]

I have changed `goal1` to `goal2`: there are no differences between my Embed table and Query Explorer. I get the expected results with `goal2completions`.

Settings in Query Explorer:

[image: Settings in Query Explorer]

[image: Analytics overview]

Can someone tell me why I'm not seeing my expected results?